# Equilateral triangle based mesh generation by intersection

Tags: computational-geometry, discretization, mesh

In work I am currently working on I need to mesh some structure with equilateral triangles to study it using a kind of discrete element method known as spring networks or Lattice model.

To mesh the structure, first I generate the equilateral triangular grid then I do the intersection between the structure and the grid.
My problem lies in the second step, the intersection between the structure to mesh and the grid, I found difficulties to solve it.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hi HoussemGhiat and welcome to scicomp!  Could you elaborate on what the "difficulties to solve it" are?  Also, is there a particular reason why you need equilateral triangles?  Many complex geometries cannot be meshed by equilateral triangles alone.

Comment: The first problem I am facing is: when I have a geometric form to mesh first I try to find all the points of the grid that lies on the boundary or inside this geometry, then I will try to get all the edges that both ends are in the set of points that belong to this geometry( my mesh constitute of nodes and edges no faces) here I don't see a way to do this.

The equilateral triangles is a limitation of the model that I am working on, the equation developed are usable just in the case of equilateral triangular mesh.

I am using C++ and CGAL, VTK.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean when you say "the intersection between the structure to mesh and the grid"?  It might help if you post a picture explaining how you are forming the meshes.

Comment: like you can see in the image above, the geometry to be meshed is in Yellow and the grid is in white the grid is generated separately the geometry is put on the grid and all the edge that lies inside the geometry are taken and we get a mesh for this geometry. Of course the more the grid is fine the more the geometry is represented adequately.

Comment: Is having precisely equilateral triangles completely necessary? If having triangles that are approximately equilateral is acceptable, then programs like Shewchuk's triangle or gmsh by Geuzaine could work.

Comment: Having equilateral triangles is necessary, other way the code will provide wrong results.